# How can i filter taxonomy by another taxonomy term with views (term)?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I explain my question : 
i have a main content -> travel,
Then i have taxonomy term -> country.

On my taxonomy term country, i put a taxonomy term : "tagcountry" (with words like "dangerous", "safe",...)

My question is simple, how can i create a block with related taxonomy "tagcountry"?

For instance, i would like to have in my taxonomy page country "Syria" tagged by "dangerous", a block with the first 10 countries that are tagged "dangerous".
It's quiet easy to achieve this with "content", but i fail with "taxonomy".

Thanks in advance for your answers !

---

Edit : I already tried with all contextual filters : nothing worked. Except when i provide a manual value like this (but it's not dynamic) :

[image]

But when i want to use "taxonomy ID from url" with specified vocabulary ("Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks"). It doesn't work...

Comment: Try to describe what you have already tried, where it fails. Ideally also provide a link (e.g. to pastebin) with the view code that you have so far. Screenshots can be of help too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution with references module :

https://drupal.org/project/references

If some of you want to use custom taxonomy, may be it's better to use nodes with "node reference" than taxonomy...